# DM and CM EMI emissions measurement in LTspice

Tags: noise, ltspice, emc, common-mode, common-emitter

according to a youtube video V(SMA1,SMA2) is equal to 2*DM_noise and V(SMA1)+v(SMA2) is equal to 2*CM_noise. it is said that they must be divided by 2 and also multiplied by 1,000,000 to result in dBuV scaling. but the plotted results are 500,000*V(SMA1,SMA2) and 1,000,000*(V(SMA1)+v(SMA2)). the question is, why DM is divided by 2 but CM is not?

[image]

this is actually just the LISN part of my schematic. At the right side a switching circuit is operating and generating noise (not shown in this figure). Anyway, my question is about measuring dm and cm noises by the shown LISN in LTSpice, regardless of the upstream converter.

[image]

Comment: You are using a 311 V signal as input, but the test case implies measuring *noise*. Does that video use a voltage source with these settings, too?

Comment: @a concerned citizen, this is actually just the LISN part of my schematic. At the right side a switching circuit is operating and generating noise (not shown in this figure). Anyway, my question is about measuring dm and cm noises by the shown LISN in LTSpice, regardless of the upstream converter.

Comment: (When using `@`, the names must not contain spaces. Use it with `@<TAB>` to cycle between the available names. if none comes out then there is no need for `@`).

Comment: What I meant was that, if you want to emasure *noise* then you have no noise source in there, only a brute power supply (AC, DC, doesn't matter). So if you're interested in noise then you should add a noise source, be it for a `.NOISE`, `.AC`, or `.TRAN` analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the terms for CM and DM noise need to be divided by two. In the picture below you can see how CM and DM currents are flowing and how they can be separated.

[image: CM DM noise separation with LISN]
<sub>Source: [AnalogDialogue article](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/separating-common-mode-and-differential-mode-emissions-in-conducted-emissions-testing.html)</sub>